# Cakephp . Pass user ip to Form

Tags: php, cakephp, ip

I'm tryin to pass user ip usign Form, but i can;t handle this. Even googling, and searching in cookbook is useless in my case.

How to pass user ip in form during creating some post ? ofcourse using cakephp

This is all my Form

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Info'); ?>
Tytuł :
<?php echo $this->Form->input(__('title',true),array('class'=>'form-controll')); ?>
Treść newsa: 
<?php echo $this->Form->input(__('body',true),array('class'=>'form-controll')); ?>
<?php $this->Form->input(__('ip',true)) = $this->request->clientIp(); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->submit(__('Dodaj newsa',true),array('class'=>'btn btn-success')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

and i'm focusing on this particular thing

```
<?php $this->Form->input(__('ip',true)) = $this->request->clientIp(); ?>
```

ofcourse it's wrong, but i tried different combinations.
Please give me some tip.
Regards

edit.

i would like to pass it to table in my db base, that's why i'm tryin to use some kind of post.

edit2

thanks to iso27002
i solved my problem as folows, 
in controller

```
$this->request->data['Info']['ip'] = $this->request->clientIp();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the function right, `$this->request->clientIp();`, but you need to call it from your Controller. So rather than using a hidden field with this value instead just append it yourself to the request data. For example,

`$this->request->data['Info']['ip'] = $this->request->clientIp();`

Then you can utilise the same code logic you would if there was a hidden field containing client IP.

Comment: thank You :)
just before your post i was trying do this in similar way, and my final code before your post was $this->data['Info']['ip'] = $this->request->clientIp();

i just added "request" and it works. thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't. The IP is part of the request and the controller.
You just use it there - no need to pass it through a form via post.

Just use

```
env('REMOTE_ADDR');
```

inside your controller.

Comment: i didn't mentioned before, i would like to use post becouse i would like to input this ip adres into db table.

Comment: Doesnt change it - you can add the there. See ["Default values - Hidden"](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/23/working-with-forms/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of server variables would contains client IP:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']
```

You can make some if..elseif..else statements to get correct client ip address. You don't need include ip as form field. Get ip addres inside post url, using Cake Request class or directly from `$_SERVER` global variable.
If you're using ip address as validator of something, remember, the client can change form field values even if they are hidden. Apologize my general way to speak, I never pass from Cake's Getting Started.